# Enabling DHL Marketplace in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, dhl

How can I add [DHL Market Place](https://marketplace.magento.com/dhl-module-shipping-m2.html) in my Magento 2 admin? Been searching on how to enable it but can't find any solution. Should I just copy the download file into the `app` folder? or do I need to go to the admin panel?

Note: Beginner here

Comment: Yes, you should download the extension from marketplace  and place it inside the app/code then run bin/magento setup:upgrade and bin/magento cache:clean and then go to the admin -> stores ->configuration and find the vendor under sales tab.

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran should I retain the folder name or should I create a new one? dhl-module-shipping-m2-0.9.0 this is the name of the downloaded file

Comment: Open registration.php from the module and that should be your folder name, say it DHL_Shipping means then the directory should look like DHL/Shipping/ then all the files block controller etc.,

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information of installation of module and how to use this module in extension' user guide. you can find this on above link given by you. But for you i am adding url here. Open that url and read user guide, you will find your answer.

[User guide](https://marketplace.magento.com/media/catalog/product/dhl-module-shipping-m2-0-9-0-ce/user_guides.pdf)

Please let me know still if you have any question.